# Symfony, twig template - string concatenation

Tags: php, html, twig, string-concatenation

I've got a project written in PHP in which I am using Symfony framework. This piece of code from Twig template doesn't work.

```
        {% for restaurant in restaurants %}
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
            <div class="thumbnail restaurant-thumbnail">
                <img src="{{ asset('build/images/'.'image1.8e9b4ad0.jpg') }}" alt="cannot load image" class="restaurant-image">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{ restaurant.getName() }}</h3>
                    <p>{{ restaurant.getShortDescription() }}</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Więcej informacji</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

When I change this

```
<img src="{{ asset('build/images/'.'image1.8e9b4ad0.jpg') }}"
```

to that:

```
<img src="{{ asset('build/images/image1.8e9b4ad0.jpg') }}"
```

code works. I don't know why.

Comment: What a problem if you use this->>>>>>>>>  <img src="{{ asset('build/images/image1.8e9b4ad0.jpg') }}"
it is right

Comment: No, because I want to substitute a variable to have sth like that:
<img src="{{ asset('build/images/'. variable ) }}"

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee. It worked.

Comment: Please mark as duplicate then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz try it

```
 <img src="{{ asset('build/images/') }}{{'image1.8e9b4ad0.jpg'}}" alt="cannot load image" class="restaurant-image">
```

if you want to use  Variable

```
  <img src="{{ asset('build/images/') }}{{variable}}" alt="cannot load image" class="restaurant-image">
```